# Gatling stress tool + Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gatling

I try to record script via `gatling` recorder.

-> click on Start!

-> set proxy to address `127.0.0.1` and port `8000` (in my system config)

-> load page: `http://185.28.103.176:4000/`

-> I can see some logs in "Executed Events", but also error and warn in gatling console:

```
D:\Downloads\gatling\bin>recorder.bat
GATLING_HOME is set to "D:\Downloads\gatling"
JAVA = ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe""
21:27:15.922 [WARN ] i.n.b.ServerBootstrap - Unknown channel option 'TCP_NODELAY' for channel '[id: 0x80873c61]'
21:27:19.082 [ERROR] i.g.r.h.h.u.HttpsUserHandler - Handshake failure with /185.28.103.176:4000
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 485454502f312e31203430302042616420526571756573740d0a636f6e6e656374696f6e3a20636c6f73650d0a7365727665723a20436f77626f790d0a646174653a204d6f6e2c203230204d617220323031372032303a32373a313720474d540d0a636f6e74656e742d6c656e6774683a20300d0a0d0a
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.)
        ....
21:27:19.083 [WARN ] i.n.c.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 485454502f312e31203430302042616420526571756573740d0a636f6e6e656374696f6e3a20636c6f73650d0a7365727665723a20436f77626f790d0a646174653a204d6f6e2c203230204d617220323031372032303a32373a313720474d540d0a636f6e74656e742d6c656e6774683a20300d0a0d0a
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.)
        ....
```

And I can't to continue on my page. (without proxy, page is working)

//page is correctly working only on Chrome and Nighty browsers

edited:
dev config:

```
config :chatier, Chatier.Endpoint,
check_origin: false,
code_reloader: true,
debug_errors: true,
http: [port: 4000],
https: [
certfile: "priv/keys/dev/gatlingCA.cert.pem",
ciphers: [
  "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
  ...
],
    dhfile: "priv/keys/dev/dh-params.pem",
    honor_cipher_order: true,
    keyfile: "priv/keys/dev/gatlingCA.key.pem",
    max_connections: :infinity,
    otp_app: :chatier,
    port: 4443,
    reuse_sessions: true,
    secure_renegotiate: true,
    versions: [:'tlsv1.2'],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not configured to serve up over SSL.  Your gatling tool is requesting SSL it appears but your web or apps server isn't configured to handle SSL requests.

Comment: I edit my first post. I think, I have correct SSL config.
I can also connect to https://185.28.103.176:4443/

Comment: The log output though shows your tool is trying to access port 4000, not 4443

Comment: because I acces to port 4000, not 4443

Comment: Your first comment mentioned port 4443 for SSL. Port 4000 definitely is not configured for SSL.

Comment: I have both, 4000 for http and 4443 for https

Comment: I understand.  Your log output you pasted shows the tool is trying to hit port 4000, not 4443